# SerialForms.pas(17): W1010 Method 'Create' hides virtual method of base type 'TComponent'

Tags: сборка, delphi, delphi-7, функции

Я создал класс

```
  FormInfo = class (TComponent)
  private
    FLeftValue : Integer;
    FTopValue : Integer;
    FHeightValue : Integer;
    FWidthValue : Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(
      AOwner : TComponent;
      leftvalue : integer;
      topvalue : integer;
      heightvalue : integer;
      widthvalue : integer);
  protected
    procedure GetChildren(Proc: TGetChildProc; Root: TComponent); override;
    function  GetChildOwner: TComponent; override;
    //procedure SetParentComponent(Value : TComponent); override;
  published
    property LeftValue : Integer read FLeftValue write FLeftValue;
    property TopValue : Integer read FTopValue write FTopValue;
    property HeightValue : Integer read FHeightValue write FHeightValue;
    property WidthValue : Integer read FWidthValue write FWidthValue;
  end;
```

который в дальнейшем используестя для сериализации формы. У метода Create есть следующая реализация

```
constructor FormInfo.Create(AOwner: TComponent; leftvalue, topvalue, heightvalue,
  widthvalue: integer);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FLeftValue := leftvalue;
  FTopValue := topvalue;
  FHeightValue := heightvalue;
  FWidthValue := widthvalue;
end;
```

В результате сборки я получаю предупреждение

```
[dcc32 Warning] SerialForms.pas(17): W1010 Method 'Create' hides virtual method of base type 'TComponent'
```

Что надо сделать, чтобы избавиться от этого предупреждения без потери функциональности приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать директиву **reintroduce**

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: назвать конструктор по другому, не Create. Напр. CreateNew (так принято называть конструктор в фабриках, а здесь речь о фабрике идет, если я всё правильно понял).